# iOS 14: Apple Reject "would like to find and connect to devices on your local network"

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

[image: My info.splist]Guideline 5.1.1 - Legal - Privacy - Data Collection and Storage
We noticed that your app requests the user’s consent to access the local network information, but doesn’t sufficiently explain the use of the local network information in the purpose string.
To help users make informed decisions about how their data is used, all permission request alerts need to specify how your app will use the requested information.
Next Steps
Please revise the relevant purpose string in your app’s Info.plist file to specify why your app needs access to the user's local network information. Make sure the purpose string includes an example of how the user's data will be used.
You can modify your app's Info.plist file using the property list editor in Xcode.
Resources

- See examples of helpful, informative purpose strings.
- Review a list of relevant property list keys.
  So How can I resolve it ? Thanks all!

Comment: And, what is your issue? Apple **requires** various things to protect the user. Obviously, something in your `Info.plist` isn't up to their standards. Look at your app's privacy settings. And yes, without a *bit* more info on your part - it's hard to help you.

Comment: I don't know What these part should I revise the relevant purpose string of in my app’s Info.plist

Comment: I updated my image info.splist.

Comment: You need to provide a "privacy - local network usage description" in your `info.plist` to explain why your app access the local network.  E.g. "XYZ will discover display devices on your local network to show content" or whatever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the message, you are trying to access the local network information in your project:

> We noticed that your app requests the user’s consent to access the
> local network information, but doesn’t sufficiently explain the use of
> the local network information in the purpose string.

In the [document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/nslocalnetworkusagedescription) of `NSLocalNetworkUsageDescription`:

> Any app that uses the local network, directly or indirectly, should
> include this description. This includes apps that use Bonjour and
> services implemented with Bonjour, as well as direct unicast or
> multicast connections to local hosts.

So you need to add this key in the `info.plist` and add description there.

Comment: @BaoBao Does my solution work for you? If yes, can you please accept it (click the ☑️ in the upper left corner of this answer ) so that we can help more people with same problem:).

Comment: Yes, I'm waiting for response of reviewer. I will click the ☑️ in the upper left corner of this answer.

Comment: Yes, It worked for me. Thank you so much!